# String input from a user without declaring size of it before

Tags: c

I couldn't find anywhere on internet how to take string from a user without declaring its size in advance (like `char str[20];`) in C. I want a program to reserve just enough memory for it.

Comment: Dynamic allocation (and reallocation) while reading one (or more) character at a time. Otherwise it's not possible unless you know the actual input size beforehand (and can guarantee that it won't change, which isn't really possible).

Comment: [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) if using in a posix system.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the terminal program itself is likely to limit the number of characters that the user can enter at one time. That limit could be 2K characters, for example. So the typical solution is to create a single large buffer for input, and then copy the string to a correctly sized buffer once its length is known.

Comment: Thank you guys very much :)

Comment: @kaylum has the best answer for strings. For the general problem of buffering input of unknown length (say you were reading a list of integers into an `int` array), there's `realloc` to extend a `malloc`ed buffer when it's full.